What is the maximum size of file I can read using `dbutils.fs.head()` method?
I have a file of about 200 MB which I am trying to read. This file will increase in size in future data loads. So, what is the maximum file size which I can handle using the dbutils.fs.head() method.
I am using unity catalog so can't use the python open() method.

The dbutils.fs.head() method in Databricks is meant to read only the initial bytes of a file, so it is not ideal for handling large files. This method is usually used to quickly preview the content or structure of a file. If you are dealing with a 200 MB file, dbutils.fs.head() should work fine. If you need to deal with large files, you can use the spark.read.csv() method to read the file as a Spark DataFrame. This method can handle large files and can process files of any size supported by the storage system you are using.
import os
file_path = "/databricks-datasets/Rdatasets/data-001/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv"
file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
print("File size:", file_size, "bytes")

File size: 3192560 bytes

For example, I am trying to read a file using spark.read.csv():
df = spark.read.csv("/databricks-datasets/Rdatasets/data-001/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)
df.show()

Results:
+---+-----+---------+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+
|_c0|carat|      cut|color|clarity|depth|table|price|   x|   y|   z|
+---+-----+---------+-----+-------+-----+-----+-----+----+----+----+
|  1| 0.23|    Ideal|    E|    SI2| 61.5| 55.0|  326|3.95|3.98|2.43|
|  2| 0.21|  Premium|    E|    SI1| 59.8| 61.0|  326|3.89|3.84|2.31|
|  3| 0.23|     Good|    E|    VS1| 56.9| 65.0|  327|4.05|4.07|2.31|
|  4| 0.29|  Premium|    I|    VS2| 62.4| 58.0|  334| 4.2|4.23|2.63|
|  5| 0.31|     Good|    J|    SI2| 63.3| 58.0|  335|4.34|4.35|2.75|
|  6| 0.24|Very Good|    J|   VVS2| 62.8| 57.0|  336|3.94|3.96|2.48|
|  7| 0.24|Very Good|    I|   VVS1| 62.3| 57.0|  336|3.95|3.98|2.47|
|  8| 0.26|Very Good|    H|    SI1| 61.9| 55.0|  337|4.07|4.11|2.53|
|  9| 0.22|     Fair|    E|    VS2| 65.1| 61.0|  337|3.87|3.78|2.49|
| 10| 0.23|Very Good|    H|    VS1| 59.4| 61.0|  338| 4.0|4.05|2.39|

In the above code, specifying the inferSchema=True option, Spark will automatically infer the schema of the DataFrame based on the data in the file. Also, the header=True option assumes that the first row of the file contains the column names.
